# Create a custom attachment thumbnail for quick page load

Tags: images, attachments, thumbnails

I've been trying to find a way to create a custom image attachment thumbnail. I want to display an image attachment thumb and link to the full size. (FYI The thumb is to get quick page loading speed instead of a full size that would slow down things.)

so i'm trying to:

1. create an Image Attachment Thumbnail
2. keep it Small Size
3. be able to set a max width

The other options that I have figured out:

- to use the attachment as background-image, but that gives me a big file size.
- to manually create a thumbnail for the attachment and upload it.
- use the thumbnail setting for featured-image and change that to meet my needs, but i'm using it for the featured-image.

Is there a way to get wordpress to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Discovered that you can use the `add_image_size` function to achieve this. [Function Reference/add image size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)